# XSL-FO FOP pagebreak if table fits on a new site

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

Being quite new to the FOP and its structure, I came up with the problem that FOP creates pagebreaks within tables. I have about 20 tables which sometimes are filled with only one or two rows, but also others which could have a lot more. Now the requirement is that if a table including heading and header would fit on a blank page properly AND there is not enough space on the current page to display the table, then a pagebreak is created. So i would need a conditional pagebreak ( which I did not find) and a way to find whether the table fits on the page or not.

So are there any block-attributes I might have missed? (Speaking about block-attributes because table heading and table content are two different tables due to historical reasons)

Comment: There is no way to test if a given table fits on a single page. You can specify various desired keep-* behaviours, but if a table is longer than one page there will be at least one page break in the table (obviously).

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding [keep-together='always'](http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/prop_keep-together.asp) to `fo:block`. It will force whole `fo:block` on the same page.

Comment: Okey, this changed that my heading and content table will appear on the same page, but it doesn't solve my problem with the pagebreaks within the table